# how to open infowindow in page load in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i have one marker in google map . and it has one info window with some content . i want it should open automatically when page renders not in click event .

```
   function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(22.804270950051844, 86.18359432304942),
            myOptions = {
                zoom: 14,
                center: myLatLng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            },
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions),
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png',
                label: "1",
            });
        var contentString = 'no 1';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });
        marker.addListener('click', function () {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
         infowindow.open(map, marker);
        marker.setMap(map);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't put in listener but in body initMap code

```
  function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(22.804270950051844, 86.18359432304942),
            myOptions = {
                zoom: 14,
                center: myLatLng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            },
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions),
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png',
                label: "1",
            });

        var contentString = 'no 1';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });

        infowindow.open(map, marker);

    }
```

and if you have problem with overlapping  try assigne a proper new position eg: 
(`position` by default  contains the LatLng of the object at which this info window is anchored)

```
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(22.80427+ 0.000005 , 86.18359+ 0.000005)
        });
```

Comment: its working but some design issue coming. infowindow is overlapping on marker , marker is getting hide